# Typed in "ruby -version" in terminal and got an error after switching bootdisk from HD to SSD. How do I resolve this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Installed a 2nd HD(SSD) on my MBP 15" and cloned all my files into it except the "User" folder. Deleted all the files I cloned from my original HD and left the users there and booted up my computer using SSD. Everything works, except when I check my ruby version, I get the following spilling out:

```
$ ruby -version
dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/jb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/libruby.2.1.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Volumes/HardDrive/Users/jb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

What's going on here and how would I go about solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OS X binaries (such as ruby) contain the full path of the shared libraries they use, so when you run ruby it's trying to load libruby from that path - it doesn't know that the entire volume has been mounted at a different path

The easiest thing is probably to reinstall ruby - `rvm reinstall ruby-2.1.0` should do it

In theory you should be able to use `install_name_tool` to rewrite the shared library paths in the binaries but it is almost certainly more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Thanks! I browsed around and found `rvm install 2.1.1 --disable-binary`. Would you have recommended adding `--disable-binary`?